# How to add custom auth mechanism for node-xmpp Client?

Tags: node.js, node-xmpp

Can I use customs auth mechanisms in node-xmpp without forking it? I need to auth with mechanism very similar to **X-OAUTH2**, but with other title and simpler auth() method( see [code](https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp/blob/master/lib/xmpp/sasl.js) for more information).